# Getting Java Error Message - JAVA_HOME is not valid:

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk, openjdk

I'm trying to set up OpenDaylight which is a SDN controller on Ubuntu Virtual Box. The version of Ubuntu is 18.04.
OpenDaylight requires java-8-openjdk-amd64 and I have installed it successfully:

See below:

```
liv@liv-VirtualBox:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Have also set the `JAVA_HOME` path by adding the below to `/etc/environment`:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"
```

I checked the JAVA path by typing in `echo $JAVA_HOME` at the terminal CLI and the echo result being `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

So, I'm thinking that I have covered all the steps.. :)

When I try and launch OpenDaylight, I get the following error:

```
karaf: JAVA_HOME is not valid: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

I'm really hoping someone can help me to fix the issue I'm having and would be extremely grateful for anyone to offer a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

JAVA_HOME should be set as "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"

Comment: Hi Amutheezan
Thank you for taking the time to provide a solution. I have changed the path in /etc/environment to "JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"
however when I echo JAVA_HOME, I still get the following...

liv@liv-VirtualBox:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Am I missing something? :) Are you able to tell me why my change doesn't take effect and / or how I can fix this? Appreciate your time.

Comment: restart the computer and try again. In case if you add that as a line to file to .bashrc you can just try source .bashrc  and that will sync JAVA_HOME correctly with easy anyway both approaches are okay

Comment: Hi Amutheezan,Thank you so much!! :) you have solved my issue. I truly appreciate you taking the time to help me with my issue..

Comment: @Liv Dont hesitate follow this  stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)